# Cannot create Windows Phone 8 project in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a copy of Visual Studio 2102 installed on my computer. Since my computer met all the requirements for the emulator (SLAT, Hardware Assisted Virtualization etc.), i downloaded the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK and proceeded to install it.

Unfortunately, i cannot create a new Windows Phone application. Project templates (Windows phone application, Pivot application, Panorama application etc) do not appear in VS2012 main page. The only available option is "Discover Windows phone tools" (which redirects you to the download page of the SDK).
I tried to uninstall everything and repeat the process, but the result is the same.

I'm still able to open projects made with the old Windows phone SDK 7.1 and test them on the new emulator. This should be enough to prove that the installation was successfully completed.

I can't understand what went wrong. May you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar bug because my Visual Studio Pro is in French. When you install Windows phone SDK, an express version of vs is already installed, you can create phone project in this version and open these projects in vs pro but you cannot create phone project directly in vs pro, that's right ?

- Go to : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows Phone
- You should have a folder called 1033, it contains phone template for english version of visual studio. Copy and paste it then rename the copy in your code language (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t12k0f0.aspx , for me it's 1036).
- After that, close visual studio, launch C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat with admin rights and type : devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates /ResetSettings
- Relaunch visual studio pro, and you should have a Windows phone entry.

Comment: Thanks man, this seems to be what i was looking for.

However, what do you mean by "type : devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates /ResetSettings"? How do i "type" this?

I correctly launched "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" by clicking on "Run as administrator", but what should i do after that?

Comment: Open it in a prompt. Else you can find it in your windows start menu -> Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx -> Tools -> Developer Command prompt (don't forget to open with admin rights).

Comment: I did what you suggested, and all seemed ok as templates finally appeared. Now, when i click on one of them (e.g. Windows Phone App) and select "Windows Phone 8.0" as target operative system i get the following error:

could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80030002(STG_E_FILENOTFOUND))

Can you help me solving this issue, too?

Comment: However, I've a an idea !
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471
>>> Click on change language and pick the same as your vs current copy, i'm sure it will solve the problem.
The second time I install I didn't have the issue, may because I did that !

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't seem to work. However, i solved my problem by installing the english version of VS2012. Thank you, i really appreciated your help ;)

Comment: I've got a similar problem, but I've got an english VS and the templates are completely missing...

Answer (score 0):

Parallels provides a very good knowledge-base article on fixing this problem:

[KB: Running Windows 8 Phone emulator in the Windows 8 virtual machine](http://kb.parallels.com/en/115211)

Answer (score 0):

Copy lang files also in:
...\IDE\ItemTemplates...
...\WindowsPhone\ProjectTemplates...
It helped me!